# Where can I get a feedback for my lyrics from native english speaker?

Tags: feedback, lyrics

I really love to write lyrics for my music in English, I like how it sounds but this language isn't my first one and obviously I can't write natural texts, sometimes I even make common mistakes. I would be so greatful and pleased to get thoughtful feedback on my lyrics concerning just form, not meaning. How and where can I get this proper feedback just to make sure I wrote a natural text in English language?

Answer (score 1):

After you have asked a few more questions here, you could join the chatroom at [EL&U](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage-multi-layered-discourse-room). The people there are quite friendly and might give you useful feedback. You'd need to join in with them on other things a bit too.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I don't have enough "reputation" to join that chat yet, but your advice sounds useful.

Comment: Once I get enough rep here, I'll upvote your question. That should get you on your way! Won't take too long.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for that! Thank you!

Comment: @Surrey_Grin You just need to ask another question or two and then you should have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google? You are unlikely to be the first person to have this question. I get countless results. For example:

There are critique groups on Facebook, e.g. https://www.facebook.com/groups/486721968158646/ or https://www.facebook.com/groups/281626592468774/.

Many organisations offer local in-person critique meetups, e.g. https://www.instagram.com/p/CxoKICwvCB_/.

There are writing groups. Maybe there is one in your area. For example, the UK Poetry Society maintains a Young Poets Network that organises writing groups in different areas of the UK: https://ypn.poetrysociety.org.uk/opportunities_category/writing-groups/.

And you can pay professionals for feedback.

Comment: Google brought me here. I wanted to post my lyrics here, but found it inappropriate. 

You see I don't want to get professional feedback, but a respond from native english speaker that can say if he understand what I mean in my lyrics and examin whether there is any mistake.

Comment: @Surrey_Grin Yes, and did you read the rest of my answer? There will be native speakers in Facebook critique groups, for example.

Answer (score 0):

critters.org
They have a group for poetry. I'm not sure about lyrics.

Comment: The last time I looked, critters.org wasn't available to anyone in the EU due to GDPR.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that website works well in my country.